# Run action from Android using single voice command?

Tags: android, voice

Is it possible to create an app or intent in Android that is triggered by a *single* voice command, along the lines of Alexa? For example, I'd like my users to be able to say:

> OK Google, log my temperature as 38 degrees centigrade

and have this both open my temperature app, and log the temperature, within a single command.

I'm aware that at the moment I allow my users to do this with two separate voice commands, firstly:

> OK Google, open MyTemperatureApp

using an OK Google custom voice command to open the app, and then once the app is open:

> Log my temperature as 38 degrees centigrate

using a RecognizerIntent within my app to parse the phrase and log the temperature.

But I'm wondering if I can make Android work more like Alexa, defining a custom intent within a single phrase from standby.

Comment: There is only one app on play store which can get the text whatever you say to Google Now! then you can perform desired operation. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.RSen.Commandr&hl=en